# My app unexpectedly asks for notification permission when build with xcode6 for ios8

Tags: notifications, ios8, xcode6

My app asks the user for notification permissions since I build it with Xcode6 and run it on ios8.
The app does not want or need permission since we do nothing with notifications.

What is trigger for this question? What can I do to NOT get the question?
I've looked in the app-id for stuff that perhaps got added since ios8. All that is enabled there are  data protection and in app purchase (which can't be turned off).

I don't have any code in the app asking or needing notification permission.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything to hide this.

In iOS8 , the OP asks for permissions even for local notifications.

Comment: Even if we don't do anything notification related?

Comment: No, if you're not using notifications at all it won't ask. So you have probably a call or declaration somewhere.